# Apache can not start after configuring wamp environment（2 Version of PHP on an apache）

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Problem: Using Apache2.4 to configure php7.0.6 and php7.2.1, php7.0.6 can be started, but php7.2.1 does not start.
httpd.conf configuration parameters are as follows:

```
<IfDefine php7.0.6>
    LoadModule php7_module "C:/php7.0.6/php7apache2_4.dll"
    PHPIniDir "C:/php7.0.6"
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine php7.2.1>
    LoadModule php7_module "C:/php7.2.1/php7apache2_4.dll"
    PHPIniDir "C:/phip7.2.1"
</IfDefine>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .inc
</IfModule>
```

The result of the terminal executing the install service command is as follows:

`C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache2.4_PHP7.2.1" -D php7.2.1`

`Installing the 'Apache2.4_PHP7.2.1' service`

`The 'Apache2.4_PHP7.2.1' service is successfully installed.`

`Testing httpd.conf....`

`Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.`

Terminal test installation seems to be OK:

`C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -n "Apache2.4_PHP7.2.1" -t
Syntax OK`

However, the service Apache2.4_PHP7.2.1 created can not be started. The error.log file has the following error record:

`[Tue Jan 09 10:51:37.960749 2018] [core:warn] [pid 12396:tid 604] AH00098: pid file C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?`

PHP extensions are all annotated extensions, PHP.ini file is the initial state, only modified extension_dir.

Comment: Fully uninstall apache ->restart system-> install again

Comment: `core:warn` is not an `error`, just telling you some info about the state when starting. Your httpd process is probably running fine.

Comment: I add path of PHP7.2.1 to environment variable, then everything goes right. There are two PHP path in EV, is that right?